# Как сделать сайт доступный только для подписчиков канала на youtube?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Возможно ли такое сделать вообще? Чтоб контент могли просматривать только те кто подписан на канал на youtube. А если человек отписался то контент для него закрывается.

Comment: Конечно возможно

Comment: изучайте [апи](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) и найдете ответ как

Comment: Вроде ж YouTube - это Google аккаунт, сделаете авторизацию через YouTube сможете связать пользователя на сайте с пользователем ютуба, а дальше уже смотреть на подписчиков